# Optional static value in attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, optional-parameters, attributerouting

I'm using attribute routing for a current project and in a few of the routes, I'm using some optional parameters. So for a URL like...

`/detail/H40466/wood-to-wood-foundation-and-boxspring-frame-assembly`

With its route definition like...

`[Route("detail/{productName}/{applicationSlug?}")]`

The `wood-to-wood...` is an optional parameter. What I'm wanting to do (if possible) is to have a static value only show up if the second parameter is present. Something like...

`/detail/H40466/for/wood-to-wood-foundation-and-boxspring-frame-assembly`

Where the word `for` is only part of the url when the last optional parameter is present. Is there any mechanism available to accomplish this beyond setting up another action that maps to that route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define 2 different routes for the same action method. In that case, the "optional" parameter should be required for one route and not present on the other.

```
[Route("detail/{productName}/for/{applicationSlug}", Order = 1)]
[Route("detail/{productName}", Order = 2)]
```

Comment: Is the `Order` required when defining multiple routes for the same action?

Comment: In this case, no. However, the order is indeterminate when using attribute routing unless you specify it explicitly. And since putting routes in the right order is critical it makes sense to use it at least for readability purposes so it is easy to understand what order the routes will be processed in.